# File access denied for netstandard on UWP

Tags: .net-core, uwp, .net-standard

I want to read files from UWP app, and using `broadFileSystemAccess` cap together with app's permissions set in settings. Access to files work great, but only when using Window.Storage api which is exclusive for WinRT api. My app use net standard 2.0 library, so files are readed via System.IO api, and that's where problem is, because access is denied for this api. What I determined, is that access depend on version of `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` (project's references). For v5.X access is granted, and System.IO api just works. For v6.X access is denied. Unfortunately I must use v6.X in my app and library. So question is: are there any switch / way to get access to files using System.IO api on `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` v6.X ?

Comment: Does the following could solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> File access denied for netstandard on UWP

As you mentioned, `broadFileSystemAccess` only support  `Window.Storage` api within UWP platform, If you do want to use System.IO to access the file system, we suggest you use desktop bridge extension to approach that could access file with System.IO directly. For more info please refer desktop bridge official [tutorial](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop/) .